# how to find 'é' character using cygwin and grep?

Tags: regex, cygwin, grep

I want to find french characters in my java files. They are 'é', 'à', 'ê', 'è'. I need to locate all the files containing theses 'evil' characters (so anywhere in a string).

If I use grep under cygwin to find them it does not find anything.

> grep -r -I 'é' .
>
> grep -r -I \x82 .

None of the above found anything but there is a file in '.' containing 'é' character.

Can someone help?

Thanx

Comment: You might also want to use -i tu make it case-insensitive

Comment: The representation of these strings in the file and your command line's locale need to match. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: added some details, 'mostly Mostacho'' s answer is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in cygwin, but in linux. However, I don't think their grep differs that much from the linux one. This is the simple test I did and it seems to work fine:

```
$ mkdir a_dir
$ cd a_dir
$ echo "this is a tèst" > a_file
$ grep -rl 'tèst' .
./a_file
$ cat a_file
this is a tèst
```

Can you do the same and tell me if the results are the same?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this: cat *.java | grep '[éàêè]'

Comment: The Useless Use of Cat adds no benefit whatsoever, and `grep` can't tell you which file it found the match in if you call it like this.

Comment: @tripleee: It's not a true UUOC, since the behavior differs from the version without `cat` -- for the worse, in this case.

Comment: It is useless use, i know, but i just wanted to give a clue. I usually use expressions like that to test.